# Advice on starting JS or JQuery for file processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, file-io

My knowledge on web technologies (JS, JQ) are limited and I want to start learning them. As a starting point I want to do some file processing. Because it is something I have to do for my work and was planning to do it in Java. What I basically need to do is to go through a list of text files (assembly files) in a folder and search for routines and then list them. This is the first step and is a trivial task in Java.

But I wanted to take this a step further and do it in the browser, so that others in my team also can use it without installing anything (and also to impress them a little bit in the process. since I'm the new guy in the team :-)).

So when I input the folder, the script will go through the files and search and will display results in a web page. Basically first page will be a list of files in the folder, and clicking a file name will take me to another page which displays the routines in that file.

Sorry to bother you with details, but what I actually want to know are:

1. Is this possible with JS? (to
   search for  text patterns in a file)
2. Should I start with JS or JQ? (I
       think many would recommend starting
       with JS, but since this is a side
       project and this is done purely in
       my own time, would you suggest start
       learning JQ because it's relatively
       simpler to learn (from what I have
       read) for a beginner?
3. Or should I just do the processing
   in JAva and then interface the
   results to a webpage

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other, jQuery is library written to simplify usage of JavaScript with some handy shortcuts.
I'm afraid JavaScript would not be able to parse text files as its main usage is manipulating content inside browser window and limited by different security policies.
To parse files you have to chose [server side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).

Comment: Thanks Nazariy. I know Java and JS have nothing to do with each other. And it's trivial to do this in Java. But I wanted to do this in JS so that I'd be able to nicely display the results in a webpage and users can click and navigate. I think JS can do file processing as long as it's local. Atleast thats my understanding, I could be wrong.

Comment: Well, than you have to parse text in Java and return results back to browser so JavaScript can do the rest.

Comment: Thank you. That I guess is one way to do it. Downside is that people then need to run a Java app instead of opening a web page. But I guess doing this in JS alone is not possible.

Comment: I gave you link to server side languages and found some implementations for JavaScript, however it require installation of third party software. In my opinion java applet is right solution for this task.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use java to deal with the file processing, and then send the result to js script , which will show these results to users.
js's ability is limited

Comment: Thank you. I guess that is the feasible way.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, JavaScript is sandboxed within the browser, and has basically no access to the local file system. From what you have described, it sounds like your best option is to use Java to process *...whatever...*

This function has nothing to do with web browsing. Why is a browser the best tool for the job, anyway?

Comment: Thanks Matt.I was reading http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm and thought JS jas some capability to deal with local files. Why I want to be able to do in browser is that, first, its' neat to be able to do it and display it in browser, second, everybody has a browser in there PC. So it seems better than giving a java file to execute. But seems not a viable solution. Eventhough I do the processing in Java, then I still need to parse the results to JS through a file right?"

Comment: @madu: sure, if you want to write IE-only code, you can do it with ActiveX controls. I would never recommend doing this, though. Are you talking about running a Java program on the client's computer? If so, **forget JavaScript** as well; you're just making your life harder with little-to-no value-added. BTW, almost everyone has some version of Java installed these days.

Comment: So you mean what I can do with ActiveX is not possible with JS? So what you recommend is the way if I want to do this? Even I do the processing in Java, what is the best way yo pass the results back to JS to display them in a browser? Thanks.

Comment: I;m not sure what you meant by 'client's computer'. Everybody will have local copies in their PCs. I wanted to be able to write a JS (I hoped to) so that they can select their local folder (from the browser) and the JS will process the files (simple pattern matching for now) and display results in the browser. Thought that would be neater than doing it in a seperate Java program. Any other ways I can do this, say, using Pearl or Python, for example?

Comment: @madu: Sure, you can definitely do this with Java, or Python, or Perl (not Pearl). There are _lots_ of tutorials out there for basic file IO and directory traversing. Regardless, unless you're going to get into non-standard JavaScript (like ActiveX or other proprietary extensions to, say, Chrome), JavaScript is the **wrong tool for the job**.

Comment: Thanks Matt. What I wanted to know was that if it's possible to do the processing somewhere (Java, Perl, etc.) and be able to parse the results to JS so that it can display them in the browser.